Show that a foliation of $\mathbb P^2$ with a saddle-node must have another singularity $p$ which is either nonreduced or has Baum-Bott index $0$
I will be honest upfront and admit that this is exercise 1.13 from Alcides Lins Neto's book “Componentes Irredutíveis dos Espaços de Folheações”, meaning “Irreducible Components of Foliation Spaces” in Portuguese.
Let  $\omega \in \Omega^1(\mathbb C^3)$ be an integrable homogeneous $1$-form that represents a foliation $\mathcal F$ of $\mathbb P^2$ of degree $\ge 1$. (This means that $\omega$ generates the foliation $\pi^\star \mathcal F$, where $\pi : \mathbb C^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbb P^2$ is the canonical projection.) I want to show that $d\omega$ has an isolated singularity at $0 \in \mathbb C^3$ if and only if $\mathcal F$ has nondegenerate singularities whose Baum-Bott indices are all nonzero. Lins Neto defines “nondegenerate singularity” (and everything else) in terms of local coordinates (ugh!), but I think his definition essentially means “singularity whose Milnor number is $1$”.
I have managed to prove the following, slightly different statement: $d\omega$ has an isolated singularity at $0 \in \mathbb C^3$ if and only if, given a local vector field $X = F \, \partial_z + G \, \partial_w$ that generates $\mathcal F$ around a singular point $p \in  \mathbb P^2$, we have $\operatorname{tr}(DX(p)) = F_z(p) + G_w(p) = 0$. Notice that, if $p$ happens to be a nondegenerate singularity, then
$$BB(\mathcal F, p) = \dfrac {\operatorname{tr}(DX(p))^2} {\det(DX(p))} = 0.$$
However, the computation of $BB(\mathcal F, p)$ can't be simplified in such a neat way when $\det(DX(p)) = 0$.
Considering what I have already done, I think my problem reduces to proving the following: if $\mathcal F$ has a saddle-node somewhere, then it must have another singularity $p$ (necessarily elsewhere) which is either nonreduced (meaning $DX(p)$ is a nilpotent matrix) or has Baum-Bott index $0$. But I have no idea how to even begin proving that.
Any ideas?
